# Cefsharp deploy using azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, cefsharp.offscreen

I am trying to deploy a .Net Core application that uses CEFSharp to a app service on azure.

When I publish from VS2019 using a publish profile targeting azure, all necessary files for CEF to work are copied over to the app service and the application works.

If I try to publish using Devops pipeline all the file for CEF are not copied over to the app service and the application does not work.

These are the basic steps I have on the Pipeline

[image: Pipeline Steps]

This are the steps I have on the publish

[image: Deploy steps]

Can anyone help me with ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Can you share logs of you deploy step?

Comment: Sure, here it is 
[6_Azure App Service Deploy ProjectName.ReportJob.Core.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OZfXbmhjax4ez9kvOvc6YIJjiLo0mtjW/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I am figuring out that the issue is on the build, that does not copy the library files to the output build directory

Comment: I narrowed down to the problem being on the build.
For some reason the build step is building for anyCPU instead of x64, I think it is because there is a MS build before building a web application that is still done on  .NETFramework v4.6.2
I need to create a single build/publish to try it out